# Default app module when "Generate Signed APK" in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When I select Generate Signed APK... from the Android Studio menu I get the popup dialog asking which module to use. It always selects the first module (alphabetically) by default.

[image: Generate Signed APK Dialog]

My project includes 3 different projects. I usually use only one of them, which happens to be the last. So instead of going next next next, I have to stop and select the last project from the drop down.

Is there a way to tell Android Studio to select by default a different module? This should be at project level.

Comment: Hmm, why are you using generate signed APK a lot? To test the release APK I use build Variants with the proper keystores. Maybe not what you're looking for that's why I used a comment ;).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am aware of variants but that's not what I am looking for.

Comment: Any news if this is possible?